# Calculated Progress percentage not updating

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm trying to show the percent value of progression With a background worker in a Label .Im Adding Aprox. 25 K rows to a DataTable. It work fine when I set Label.Text to e.ProgressPercentage only . But when I calculate the % value, it remains same.Only after completion of the worker The label updates to 100%

```
                progressCount = report.Rows.Count;
                foreach (DataRow r in report.Rows)
                {

                        rp.pName = r[1].ToString();
                        rp.batch = r[2].ToString();
                        rp.expr = r[3].ToString();
                        rp.stock = r[5].ToString();
                        rp.rate = r[6].ToString();
                        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(i, rp);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
                        if(backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(0);
                        }
                        i++;

                }



private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        metroProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        metroProgressBar1.Maximum = progressCount;
         stock st = new stock();
        reportClass rp = (reportClass)e.UserState;
        if(!backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending)
        {
            st.stockReport.Rows.Add(rp.pName, rp.batch, rp.expr, rp.stock, rp.rate);
            metroProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            int percn = (e.ProgressPercentage / progressCount) * 100;
            metroLabel4.Text =percn.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably didn't register the event :  backgroundWorker2.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're most likely dividing an integer by an integer, which results in zero.  Cast your values to double first, do the calculation, then cast the result back to an int.

Change:

```
int percn = (e.ProgressPercentage / progressCount) * 100;
```

To:

```
int percn = (int)(((double)e.ProgressPercentage / (double)progressCount) * 100);
```